# CSS3: Box Shadow

Tags: css, box-shadow

Say you have a box and you use the box shadow css.  How could you make this apply to only the `top right bottom`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There no way for you to set which sides the box-shadow applies to.

In order to have the box shadow only apply to those side, you'd have to indent the x-axis variable like this: `box-shadow:4px 0 10px black;`.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2xFuz/